# Avoid pinching due to mirror

Tags: modeling, mirror, topology

the mirror modifier create pinching when mirroring a curve surface is there a way to avoid it ?[image]

even with a flat surface on the inner edge of the mesh there is still pinching

[image]

[image]

Comment: make sure there are no faces on the mirrored edge.

Comment: Looks like there are two problems, the vertices don't merge properly at the mirrors edge and you have two closely positioned edge loops to the center that cause a pinch when used in combination with the subsurface modifier.

Comment: is your Subsurf modifier below the Mirror? In that case, put it above

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody comes across this thread looking for the answer (because I believe OP is no longer waiting for one): If you have a SubDivision modifier, it should come AFTER the Mirror modifier, so that the transition gets smoothed.